# D3.js Circle Graph Layout not showing TypeError

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I just pretty much copied the code from http://bl.ocks.org/sjengle/5432087 but can't get it working.

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Vizualizace dat</title>
        <!--set the location of d3.js script as local, to make it work offline-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../D3_library/d3.v3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sepC_script_V3_noedit.js"></script>

        <style>
        body {
            font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }

        b {
            font-weight: 900;
        }

        .outline {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #888888;
            stroke-width: 1px;
        }

        #tooltip {
            font-size: 10pt;
            font-weight: 900;

            fill: #000000;
            stroke: #ffffff;
            stroke-width: 0.25px;
        }

        .node {
            stroke: #ffffff;
            stroke-weight: 1px;
        }

        .link {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #888888;
            stroke-weight: 1px;
            stroke-opacity: 0.5;
        }

        .highlight {
            stroke: red;
            stroke-weight: 4px;
            stroke-opacity: 1.0;
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            sep_script()
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

here is the js file:

```
function sep_script () {

var diameter = 500;
var radius = diameter / 2;
var margin = 20;

// Generates a tooltip for a SVG circle element based on its ID
function addTooltip(circle) {
    var x = parseFloat(circle.attr("cx"));
    var y = parseFloat(circle.attr("cy"));
    var r = parseFloat(circle.attr("r"));
    var text = circle.attr("id");

    var tooltip = d3.select("#plot")
        .append("text")
        .text(text)
        .attr("x", x)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("dy", -r * 2)
        .attr("id", "tooltip");

    var offset = tooltip.node().getBBox().width / 2;

    if ((x - offset) < -radius) {
        tooltip.attr("text-anchor", "start");
        tooltip.attr("dx", -r);
    }
    else if ((x + offset) > (radius)) {
        tooltip.attr("text-anchor", "end");
        tooltip.attr("dx", r);
    }
    else {
        tooltip.attr("text-anchor", "middle");
        tooltip.attr("dx", 0);
    }
}

// Draws an arc diagram for the provided undirected graph
function drawGraph(graph) {
    // create svg image
    var svg  = d3.select("body").select("#circle")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", diameter)
        .attr("height", diameter);

    // draw border around svg image
    // svg.append("rect")
    //     .attr("class", "outline")
    //     .attr("width", diameter)
    //     .attr("height", diameter);

    // create plot area within svg image
    var plot = svg.append("g")
        .attr("id", "plot")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + ", " + radius + ")");

    // draw border around plot area
    // plot.append("circle")
    //     .attr("class", "outline")
    //     .attr("r", radius - margin);

    // fix graph links to map to objects instead of indices
    graph.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
        d.source = isNaN(d.source) ? d.source : graph.nodes[d.source];
        d.target = isNaN(d.target) ? d.target : graph.nodes[d.target];
    });

    // calculate node positions
    circleLayout(graph.nodes);

    // draw edges first
    drawLinks(graph.links);
    // drawCurves(graph.links);

    // draw nodes last
    drawNodes(graph.nodes);
}

// Calculates node locations
function circleLayout(nodes) {
    // sort nodes by group
    nodes.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.group - b.group;
    });

    // use to scale node index to theta value
    var scale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, nodes.length])
        .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

    // calculate theta for each node
    nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
        // calculate polar coordinates
        var theta  = scale(i);
        var radial = radius - margin;

        // convert to cartesian coordinates
        d.x = radial * Math.sin(theta);
        d.y = radial * Math.cos(theta);
    });
}

// Draws nodes with tooltips
function drawNodes(nodes) {
    // used to assign nodes color by group
    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return d.name; })
        .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.y; })
        .attr("r", 5)
        .style("fill",   function(d, i) { return color(d.group); })
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) { addTooltip(d3.select(this)); })
        .on("mouseout",  function(d, i) { d3.select("#tooltip").remove(); });
}

// Draws straight edges between nodes
function drawLinks(links) {
    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}

// Draws curved edges between nodes
function drawCurves(links) {
    // remember this from tree example?
    var curve = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });

    d3.select("#plot").selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", curve);
}

d3.json("miserables.json", drawGraph);
}
```

and the json file is as it is (called miserables.json) - I pasted here just a part from it:

```
{
  "nodes":[
    {"name":"Myriel","group":1},
    {"name":"Napoleon","group":1},
    ...        
    {"name":"Brujon","group":4},
    {"name":"Mme.Hucheloup","group":8}
  ],
  "links":[
    {"source":1,"target":0,"value":1},
    {"source":2,"target":0,"value":8},
    ...
    {"source":76,"target":48,"value":1},
    {"source":76,"target":58,"value":1}
  ]
```

What I'm getting is this error: 
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'graph.links')
It says there is a problem with this line:

```
graph.links.forEach(function(d, i) {
```

saying null is not an object (evaluating 'graph.links')

I feel like this will be just a little thing to make it work, but can't figure out which one.

Comment: How is `drawGraph` getting its `graph` parameter?

Comment: It works absolutely fine. Here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqTUtGOzx2fQjthkpRv4?p=preview The error that you mention "`null` is not an object" is an error when the `d3.selection` failed (i.e. the HTML element was not found). Could you create a snippet of what you exactly have?

Comment: @AshtonFrench I'm thinking about it right now, too. But don't really know. The thing is though, why does the exact same code work on the plnkr...

Comment: @Shashank hah, you're right, it is running on plnkr.co. I pasted the exact same code I have on my MacBook, where I'm running a local server through python. And it works there, but still not on my MacBook, weird :/ –

Comment: @Shashank lol, guys, it works without a problem in Chrome. But Safari is still throwing that error...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what the problem was. It was working in the Chrome, not in the Safari. And now when I changed the original data for mine, it started working even in the Safari. (Fingers crossed it will keep working)